# Bluetooth paquet analyse in C language

Tags: c++, c, bluetooth, analysis

I would like to have Library in C or C++ that give me some Bluetooth paquet field (like address, RSSI, type,..) for a given Bluetooth stream.I used hcidump command but it doesn't give me what I want and with the manner that I need. i would like to write a program that do like hcidump but with my manner with parameter that I need.
I need to have Libraries or Tools and somes documentations or examples.
Sorry for my bad English. 
Thank you.

Comment: hcidump is to get the packets send/received between bluetooth host and bluetooth controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On linux you can use bluez, which is nicely done
http://www.bluez.org/download/